# SQL Select Statement - Selecting using one column equal to tow variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

in the following select statement I want to put two values when 
@PAPCOD = 'SIN' = values are 'DD' and 'SD'
and
@PAPCOD = 'ENG' = values are 'DI' and 'SI'

how can i do this. Only I can put one value

```
SELECT ISNULL((SUM(Con_Amount)),0) +
       (SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(SUM(Correspondent_Other_Payments.Oth_Pmt_Amount),0)
               FROM Correspondent_Other_Payments
                    WHERE Correspondent_Other_Payments.Oth_Cnt_Code = Contributions.Con_Cnt_Code and
                          Correspondent_Other_Payments.Oth_Prv_Code = Contributions.Con_Prv_Code and
                          Correspondent_Other_Payments.Oth_Dst_Code = Contributions.Con_Dst_Code and
                          Correspondent_Other_Payments.Oth_Cor_Code = Contributions.Con_Cor_Code and
                          Correspondent_Other_Payments.Oth_Pmt_Date = CONVERT(DATE, @PubDatE, 111) and
                          Correspondent_Other_Payments.Oth_AuditChk = 'Y')
       FROM Contributions
            INNER JOIN Correspondent_Master
                       ON Contributions.Con_Cnt_Code = Correspondent_Master.Cor_Country_Code and
                          Contributions.Con_Prv_Code = Correspondent_Master.Cor_Province_Code and
                          Contributions.Con_Dst_Code = Correspondent_Master.Cor_District_Code and
                          Contributions.Con_Cor_Code = Correspondent_Master.Cor_Code
                          WHERE Con_paper LIKE
                                               CASE
                                                    WHEN @PapCod = 'SIN' THEN
                                                         'DD'
                                                    WHEN @PapCod = 'ENG' THEN
                                                         'DI'
                                                    ELSE
                                                         @PapCod
                                               END and
                               (Con_PubDate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, @PubDatB, 111) and
                                                    CONVERT(DATE, @PubDatE, 111)) and
                                Contributions.Audit_Chk = 'Y' /* Audited */
                                GROUP BY Contributions.Con_Cnt_Code,
                                         Contributions.Con_Prv_Code,
                                         Contributions.Con_Dst_Code,
                                         Contributions.Con_Cor_Code,
                                         Contributions.Con_Paper
                                         ORDER BY Contributions.Con_Cnt_Code,
                                                  Contributions.Con_Prv_Code,
                                                  Contributions.Con_Dst_Code,
                                                  Contributions.Con_Cor_Code
```

[image: Sampal Data & Result what I Want]

Comment: I don't understand, can you add some sample data and expected output to show what you mean?

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] - including sample data as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). We don't need to read through all these columns in your actual query, we just need to understand what is it that you want to do. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Just add an OR replicate the same CASE and change the values to SD and SI.

```
DECLARE
    @t TABLE(Con_Paper VARCHAR(50), Con_Amount INT)

    INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
    ('DD', 100)
    ,('SD', 250)
    ,('BN',450)
    ,('DD',50)
    ,('DI',350)
    ,('NL',65)


DECLARE @PapCod VARCHAR(50) = 'ENG'

SELECT SUM(Con_Amount)
FROM @t
WHERE 
    (Con_paper LIKE
                   CASE
                        WHEN @PapCod = 'SIN' THEN 'DD'
                        WHEN @PapCod = 'ENG' THEN 'DI'
                        ELSE @PapCod
                   END 
    OR 
    Con_paper LIKE
                   CASE
                        WHEN @PapCod = 'SIN' THEN 'SD'
                        WHEN @PapCod = 'ENG' THEN 'SI'
                        ELSE @PapCod
                   END 
    )
```

Comment: @Mark it should work just fine,  see the above sample